# Null Pointer in Java function

Tags: java, android, function, search

I writed some search function and I got a null pointer exception when I try add element to temporary list.

User :

```
public class User {

    private Id _id;
    private String number;
    private String name;
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private List < Address > addresses;

    public Id get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(Id _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String user) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public List < Address > getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List < Address > addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}
```

Address :

```
public class Address {

    private String name;
    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;

    public Date getDateTo() {
        return dateTo;
    }

    public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
        this.dateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public Date getDateFrom() {
        return dateFrom;
    }

    public void setDateFrom(Date dateFrom) {
        this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


private List < User > findUsers(List < User > users, String park) {
    List < User > tempList = null;
    List < Address > addresses = null;
    for (User user: users) {
        addresses = user.getAddresses();
        for (Address address: addresses) {
            if (address.getName().equals(park))
                tempList.add(user);
        }
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

In line where `tempList.add(user);` is I get NPE.

Comment: You need to initialize your list.

Comment: Add `tempList = new ArrayList<>(); ` before `tempList.add(user);`. You need to take `List < User > tempList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null pointer exceptions are called when you try to run a method on a variable that points to `null`.

In your example you have

```
List<User> tempList = null;
```

then you never initialize it and later you use it as:

```
tempList.add(user);
```

All you need to do is initialize it :)

```
List<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

So, in your example:

```
private List<User> findUsers (List <User> users, String park){
    List<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    for (User user : users) {
        addresses = user.getAddresses();
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            if (address.getName().equals(park))
                tempList.add(user);
        }
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I would like to apologize, This is stupid error, and i should noticed him, btw Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: We all have those days!  Usually I just make sure to remember to upvote everyone who was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace

this

```
    List<User> tempList = null;
 List<Address> addresses = null;
```

with  this

```
List<User> tempList = new List<User>;

 List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

Comment: I would like to apologize, This is stupid error, and i should noticed him, btw Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Ok it's normal, Please make Answered Question. Thanks Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

```
List<User> tempList = null;
List<Address> addresses = null;
```

Your list are null you are never initialize them.
Add something like this:

```
List<User> tempList = new ArrayList();
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: I would like to apologize, This is stupid error, and i should noticed him, btw Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You get null on the code

```
tempList.add(user);
```

because you haven't created an object tempList;

Instead of `List<User> tempList = null;`

List is an interface thus you cannot call its constructor.

You need to use the class that implements List such as ArrayList

you need to write `List<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();`

Comment: I would like to apologize, This is stupid error, and i should noticed him, btw Thanks for your answers :)